# how to use poco library parser XML stream

Tags: xml-parsing, poco-libraries

The XML content is following:
test.xml

```
<root>
  <headers>
          <elementA>Google</elementA>
          <elementB>FaceBook</elementB> 
  </headers>
</root>
```

I want to use poco XML library parser the up XML content. 
I use the following code parser the /root/headers/elementA Node and get the content("Google");

```
std::ifstream in(“test.xml”);
Poco::XML::InputSource src(in);

Poco::XML::DOMParser parser;
Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::XML::Document> pDoc = parser.parse(&src);

Poco::XML::NodeIterator it(pDoc, Poco::XML::NodeFilter::SHOW_ELEMENTS);
Poco::XML::Node* pRootNode = it.root();
Poco::XML::XMLString xmlPath("/headers/elementA");
Poco::XML::Node * pNewNode = pRootNode->getNodeByPath(xmlPath);
```

the program running success, but the ***pNewNode*** pointer is NULL, i'am reference the poco office site document and not found any useful example. i'am also use google search the topic but still not found any useful info. 
who can help me fixed the problem. i have cost three days for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing /root in your path:

```
std::ifstream in(“test.xml”);
Poco::XML::InputSource src(in);

Poco::XML::DOMParser parser;
Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::XML::Document> pDoc = parser.parse(&src);

Poco::XML::NodeIterator it(pDoc, Poco::XML::NodeFilter::SHOW_ELEMENT);
Poco::XML::Node* pRootNode = it.root();
Poco::XML::XMLString xmlPath("/root/headers/elementA");
Poco::XML::Node * pNewNode = pRootNode->getNodeByPath(xmlPath);
std::cout << (pNewNode ? "not null" : "null") << std::endl;
```

Comment: How to understand the following code :
-----------------------------
std::string xml = "<root>"
        "<headers>"
        "<elementA>Google</elementA>"
        "<elementB>FaceBook</elementB>"
        "</headers>"
        "</root>";
it seem  the syntax have some error?

Comment: what is the error? the code compiles and runs fine.

Comment: hello Alex, please reference the next segment post. the segment can't post too more info. thank you .

Comment: you're missing the point. I have only put the xml in std::string to provide a simple/full example. you can not, of course, feed the xml string to ifstream - note that I have used std::istringstream, not std::ifstream. also, there is no need to expand your question in answers.

Comment: If i want to feed xml file to ifstream, how to do it?

Comment: exactly the same as you did it before:
`std::ifstream in(“test.xml”);
Poco::XML::InputSource src(in);`

Comment: No, it's still can't get object node:
----------------------------------
  std::ifstream in("hello.xml");
  Poco::XML::InputSource src(in);
  Poco::XML::DOMParser parser;
  Poco::AutoPtr<Poco::XML::Document> pDoc;
  pDoc = parser.parse(&src);
  Poco::XML::NodeIterator it(pDoc, Poco::XML::NodeFilter::SHOW_ELEMENT);
  Poco::XML::Node * pRootNode = it.root();
  Poco::XML::XMLString xmlPath("/root/headers/headera/");
  Poco::XML::Node * pNewNode = pRootNode->getNodeByPath(xmlPath);
std::cout << (pNewNode ? "not null" : "null") << std::endl;
-----------
the pNewNode still null.

Comment: Of course not, since there is no path `"/root/headers/headera/"` in the XML. You should look for `"/root/headers/elementA"`.

Comment: sorry, it hello.xml content:
------
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <headers>
        <headera>Hello</headera>
        <headerb>World</headerb>
    </headers>
</root>
So, the node path is OK.

Comment: Sorry, but I just re-ran the code and my answer definitely does work. Take some time to double-check what you are doing.

Comment: I have try to fixed it in multi-channel. but still can't do it. i am not sure which code is error. my work want to use poco library as a universe framework . my work is pending now.  i'm crazy.  can you help me?

Comment: That's what I've been trying to do but I can't make sense of much what you are saying. I have no idea what multi-channel is. I assume your company wants to use Poco as universal library but you don't know how to use it. Unfortunately, I can not learn for you. I can be temporarily hired to do the work, though; I do that all the time.